# Repetitive alarm using AlarmClock class

Tags: android, clock, alarm, repeatingalarm

We can set alarm in the default Clock app using AlarmClock class. Is there a way to set repetitive alarm that repeats everyday or on specific days using this AlarmClock class?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. As you can see in [the `AlarmClock` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html), it only allows you to specify (one set of) `EXTRA_HOUR`, `EXTRA_MESSAGE`, and `EXTRA_MINUTES` (and you can skip the default UI using `EXTRA_SKIP_UI`).

Yeah, this seems really dumb to me, too. What I would suggest is to register some kind of broadcast receiver or intent to be fired sometime after your alarm would ring, then set it again if you want. And while this is a less-than-ideal answer, I think it's the best you'll be able to do.

You may wish to go about requesting this as a feature (read [Life of a Bug](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-bug.html) and its linked articles for more on that), though that will only potentially add it to future versions, not past ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, this is really shocking. Since there is a way to do this using UI, shouldn't there be a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: There absolutely should be. When I read your post, I thought, "There's no way that's not in the SDK." But... apparently it's not. I'm shocked as well.

Comment: It can be done using AlarmManager, but that doesn't create an alarm in the Clock app. Right?

Comment: Correct, you'd have to use `AlarmManager` to add the alarm to the clock. Also, you may want to take a look at this: [Android AlarmClock Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git/+/062d863a156a3564a839ab5a718f31500298635f/src/com/android/alarmclock/)... I'm afraid I've not the time to commit to going through it, but you may be interested in doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try and post the results.